# Как реализовать фоновый приёмник оповещений с сервера?

Tags: android, background-task

Мне нужен фоновый процесс, который будет ожидать данные с сервера и выводить Notification о их получении. Как в обычных android приложениях как vk, facebook, whatsapp. Я думал использовать сервисы, но из-за новых ограничений android oreo нужен другой способ. JobSheduler не охота использовать из-за задержки во времени. Может есть какая-нибудь библиотека или что-то из android sdk, что может мне помощь. Желательно, поддержка c android 4.4 до 8

Comment: Используйте Firebase Cloud Messaging.

Comment: спасибо за информацию